# Efecto hover en panel C#

Tags: c#, css, windows-forms, hover

**¿Es posible realizar este efecto de animación `CSS` en un panel de WindowsForms C#?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Hago esto, pero obviamente no obtengo ese resultado:

```
    private void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panel_titulo.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    }

    private void panel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel_titulo.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
    }

    private void panel_titulo_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel_titulo.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    private void panel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         panel_titulo.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
    }
```

> He probado colocando Imágenes `Gif`  pero los gif no se reproducen cuando ejecuto la aplicación, se muestra la imagen fija sin animación.

**¿Es posible realizar este efecto?**

Entorno: Visual Studio & .NET Netframework 4

Comment: Has puesto los controladores de los eventos pero, ¿has enlazado estos con el panel?

Comment: Andres, si obtengo el efecto de los controladores de eventos que he colocado, pero quiero decir si puedo lograr el efecto que se muestra en la imagen, no como esta en los controladores con un color completo sin animación. Es si se puede obtener esa animación.

Comment: AH. Vale, Perdona. Con WPF sé que se puede hacer, pero con Windows Forms no lo se. Lo Siento. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con Windows Forms resulta bastante complicado hacer ese tipo de cosas.

Se me ocurre que podría hacerse por ejemplo creando diferentes imágenes con los distintos estados del botón e ir cambiando la propiedad `BackgroundImage` con un `Timer`.

Prueba este ejemplo. Es muy rudimentario pero puedes hacerte una idea de lo que digo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

namespace WindowsApp_C
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private readonly Color _colorRosa;
        private readonly List<Image> _imageList;
        private bool _isMouseHover;
        private int _currentImageIndex = -1;
        private readonly Timer _animationTimer;
        private readonly Button _animatedButton;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _colorRosa = Color.FromArgb(254, 0, 114);
            _imageList = CreateImages();
            _animationTimer = new Timer
            {
                Enabled = false,
                Interval = 50
            };
            _animationTimer.Tick += AnimateButton;

            _animatedButton = new Button
            {
                Name = "AnimatedButton",
                BackColor = Color.White,
                Text = @"CONTINUAR",
                ForeColor = _colorRosa,
                Left = 10,
                Top = 10,
                Width = 250,
                Height = 50,
                Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 20, FontStyle.Bold),
                FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
                FlatAppearance = {BorderColor = _colorRosa, BorderSize = 2}
            };
            _animatedButton.MouseEnter += (sender, args) =>
            {
                _animatedButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White;
                _isMouseHover = true;
                if (!_animationTimer.Enabled) _animationTimer.Start();
            };
            _animatedButton.MouseLeave += (sender, args) =>
            {
                _animatedButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = _colorRosa;
                _isMouseHover = false;
                if (!_animationTimer.Enabled) _animationTimer.Start();
            };
            Controls.Add(_animatedButton);
        }

        private void AnimateButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isMouseHover && _currentImageIndex >= _imageList.Count - 1
                || !_isMouseHover && _currentImageIndex <= 0)
            {
                _animationTimer.Stop();
                if (!_isMouseHover)
                    _animatedButton.ForeColor = _colorRosa;
                return;
            }

            _currentImageIndex += _isMouseHover ? 1 : -1;
            _animatedButton.BackgroundImage = _imageList[_currentImageIndex];
            _animatedButton.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        private List<Image> CreateImages()
        {
            var lista = new List<Image>();
            int width = 250;
            int height = 50;
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(_colorRosa))
            using (SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= width; i += 10)
                {
                    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
                    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                    {
                        gfx.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, width, height);
                        gfx.FillRectangle(brush, width / 2 - i / 2, 0, i, height);
                    }
                    lista.Add(bmp);
                }
            }
            return lista;
        }
    }

}
```

En este formulario creo el botón a animar y lo añado al formulario.

El método `CreateImages` crea una serie de imágenes con una barra vertical rosa que se va agrandando hasta ocupar todo el ancho del botón.

Los eventos `MouseEnter` y `MouseLeave` se encargan de arrancar el `Timer` que ejecuta la animación.

El método que ejecuta el `Timer` se encarga de ir reemplazando las imágenes en el `BackgroundImage` del botón, hacia adelante o hacia atrás en la lista de imágenes dependiendo de si el ratón está sobre el botón o fuera de éste.

Evidentemente el efecto estaría más logrado si el texto estuviese también en la imagen, aunque esto provocaría que no pudieras modificarlo a través de la propiedad `Text` del control. A no ser que generaras las imágenes dinámicamente como lo hago yo en el ejemplo...

Puede haber otras formas de hacerlo, pero ninguna va a ser sencilla.

Comment: Comprendo, si en WindowsForms todas serán complicadas, pero esta me sirve para adaptarla a lo que necesito. Gracias.

Comment: En el método `AnimateButton` ¿Qué significa esta expresión `? 1 : -1;` ?

Comment: `? :` es un operador ternario, si se cumple la condición anterior a `?` devuelve el primer valor, si no el segundo. En este caso: `_isMouseHover ? 1 : -1` si `_isMouseHover` es verdadero devuelve `1` (suma 1 al índice de la imagen a mostrar), si es falso devuelve `-1` (resta 1 al índice de la imagen a mostrar)

Comment: Perfecto, Gracias!